# How to compare two arrays and find the the match (0/1) in an array in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Love Arrays in Clickhouse!

At the moment, we are trying to engineer a solve that requires us to find whether elements in array1 exist in array2 regardless of the order.

For e.g.

```
array1= ['x','y','z']
array2= ['a','x','c']

Then the return that we want is [1,0,0]
```

1. Is there a simple out-of-the-box way to accomplish this?
2. This is part of a bigger query implying that the result from this array comparison will be used as part of the arrayMap((a,b) -> a*b, result, metric_array) -- more of an inline filtering.
3. If there is any way this can be done, the performance will improve drastically!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT
    ['x', 'y', 'z'] AS a1,
    ['a', 'x', 'c'] AS a2,
    arrayMap(x -> has(a2, x), a1) AS result

/*
┌─a1────────────┬─a2────────────┬─result──┐
│ ['x','y','z'] │ ['a','x','c'] │ [1,0,0] │
└───────────────┴───────────────┴─────────┘
*/
```

---

This solution looks ineffective, but make sense to check it too:

```sql
SELECT
    ['x', 'y', 'z'] AS a1,
    ['a', 'x', 'c'] AS a2,
    arrayIntersect(a1, a2) AS a3,
    arrayMap(x -> has(a3, x), a1) AS result

/*
┌─a1────────────┬─a2────────────┬─a3────┬─result──┐
│ ['x','y','z'] │ ['a','x','c'] │ ['x'] │ [1,0,0] │
└───────────────┴───────────────┴───────┴─────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir -- This is perfect. I am embarrassed about my own thinking (see below for my hack).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.google.com.hk/amp/s/clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/amp/

The operation should be

**has(arr, elem)**

```
   SELECT has([1, 2, NULL], NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. I am sorry, I should have been more explicit - need this within Clickhouse for a table that holds records >300M.

Comment: @calgs ok I am checking

Comment: Thanks again Frank! You are right however, I guess I am looking at an alternative way of doing something like this hasAny(arr1, arr2) returning [arr3] with 0s and 1s.
Currently if I do  select hasAny(['x','y','z'],['a','x','c']) - this will return 1 whereas, I am looking for [1,0,0]

Answer (score 1):

Little convoluted, but works for sure!

```
WITH 
    ['x', 'y', 'z'] AS i, 
    ['a', 'x', 'c'] AS j
SELECT arraySlice(arrayMap(m -> (m - 1), arrayEnumerateUniq(arrayConcat(j, i))), length(j) + 1) AS final
```

In step by step form

```
WITH 
    ['x', 'y', 'z'] AS i, 
    ['a', 'x', 'c'] AS j
SELECT 
    arrayConcat(j, i) AS k, 
    arrayEnumerateUniq(k) AS l, 
    arrayMap(a -> (a - 1), l) AS m, 
    arraySlice(m, length(j) + 1) AS final
```